# Comic about a space shuttle carrying the crew through space dragons

Tags: story-identification, comics, spaceship

I could only read the climax of a comic novel which was published in a magazine.  The ending was as follows:

The hero and and his crew are sailing in a space shuttle. The hero, who looks like a cyborg is saying that he was given half the life span of a space dragon (means the dragons are flying in space, not in air), by a witch-like lady. The story ends where their space ship is approached by lots of space dragons, but they manage to sail through.

Further details:

1. It was a comic book published in the 20<sup>th</sup> century.
2. The drawings were all quite realistic and followed the western/american art style.
3. All the human characters looked like white people.
4. The witch had given some job to the hero, for which she gave him the half life of the dragon.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else you remember?

Comment: Fixed for you but so you're aware to get a numbered list use `1. 2.` etc. instead of `1, 2,` etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comics belonged to an Indian comic series, named *Sahasi Arjun*. It had four parts, and the ending narrated in the question should belong to the last part; cover page of which is attached here:

[image]

The magazine was discontinued and the copies are not available (neither seen online). Some online threads discussing about them can be seen here:

1, http://jkini.blogspot.com/2007/11/sahasi-arjun-kannada-comics.html

2, https://www.reddit.com/r/india/comments/1h9dr1/anyone_else_read_this_as_a_kid_been_trying_to/